# Circles coming out as ovals - set aspect ratio in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, aspect-ratio

I have a graph that plots a series circles, however, because of the axes they aren't coming out as circles, but as ovals, as you can see in the image below. I know this is a reoccurring problem, and there are many questions like this... However I can't find anything that helps me! I've tried putting in `fig = plt.figure(0, figsize=(14.5, 1.75))` which does slightly help, but maybe `ax.set_aspect()` however, using scalars for this hasn't helped much either!

[image]

For this plot, the line marked *** is not there

my code is as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect(???)#*** not sure if this should be here or not
plt.axis([-5, 20, -1, 1])

circle1 = plt.Circle((-1,0.25), radius=0.2, color='c')
circle2= plt.Circle((4,-0.5), radius=0.5, color='m')

plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle1)
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the aspect to be `equal` but you will also need to choose similar sizes for both axis as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis([-5, 5, -5, 5])

circle1 = plt.Circle((-1, 0.25), radius=0.2, color='c')
circle2 = plt.Circle((4, -0.5), radius=0.5, color='m')

ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.add_artist(circle2)

plt.show()
```

Which would display as follows:
[image]

Comment: However, I'm using pieces of data for the circle (4th column represents the value of the y-axis). So is there a way to do this keeping that same axis?

Comment: You can use any axis you need, using `equal` will keep the circles circular, but you will end up with a rectangular plot.

Comment: Ok, so would the only way these could appear as circles is to have them written as ellipse's? Thanks for your help